# delete data in aso cube

Tags: hyperion, essbase

I have been trying to delete data from aso application using maxl script, user wants data to be reloaded in 2015 again so I have been trying to delete it for only December month to see whether it works or not

```
alter database 'BFCVASOb'.'BFCVASOb' clear data in region '{[AOD 2015-12],[Measures]}';
```

I get this error:

> dimension signature mismatch in function set constructor

Answer (score 0):

You might try using CrossJoin to see if it works. Right now you are only clearing a very specific tuple of data (granted, it's a test):

```
alter database 'BFCVASOb'.'BFCVASOb' clear data in region 'CrossJoin({[AOD 2015-12]},{[Measures]})';
```

Comment: I ran you query but Im getting syntax error in input MDX query line on 1 at token ')'